# Scala ifNotPresent concise form

Tags: scala, collections, scala-option

I have the following collection:

```
private val commandChain: mutable.Buffer[mutable.Buffer[Long]] = ArrayBuffer()
```

I need to do the following:

```
def :->(command: Long) = {
  commandChain.headOption match {
    case Some(node) => node += command
    case None => commandChain += ArrayBuffer(command)
  }
}
```

Is there more concise form of this than pattern matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just go with a simple `if`...`else` statement. No pattern matching and no `Option` unwrapping.

```
def :->(command: Long): Unit = 
  if (commandChain.isEmpty) commandChain += ArrayBuffer(command)
  else                      commandChain.head += command
```

BTW, this is way more mutable data structures and side effects than is seen in most idiomatic (i.e. "good") Scala.

Comment: You mean this is faster?

Comment: Perhaps, but I think you'd be hard pressed to find a measurable difference in performance. This is just slightly more concise and offers a bit more readability and clarity-of-purpose, IMHO.